# How to grant an IAM role access to AWS RDS MySQL DB

Tags: amazon-rds

I have a MySQL DB running in AWS RDS. I'm using IAM authentication. I was successfully able to use IAM authentication with normal users.

Now, I have a role called "Insight_Data_Processing". I'm creating Lambda functions that run under this role.

When trying to create a user for this role in the DB, I'm getting an error:

```
mysql> CREATE USER Insight_Data_Processing IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';
ERROR 1470 (HY000): String 'Insight_Data_Processing' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)
```

Now, role names cannot be changed (see [Rename an IAM Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488833/rename-an-iam-role) ). And I'm using this role for multiple related Lambda functions, so don't want to create yet another role.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You got the parameters wrong. It should be

CREATE USER  IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as '';

The local account can be anything