# Need to make an identical copy of AWS IAM role (including policies and trust relationship it has)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a IAM role (with many policies and a trust relationship in it). I used this in building a AWS Cognito User Pool.  However, this IAM role will be deleted soon.

Making a copy manually will be a chore and also not repeatable. I would like to make a copy either via CLI or script of some other repeatable way.

So far, I have searched through stackoverflow and google, but failed to find anything relevant.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you will need to use:

- [`list_role_policies()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_role_policies) to obtain the names of **inline policies** attached to the role
- [`get_role_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_role_policy) to retrieve **inline policies**
- [`list_attached_role_policies()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_attached_role_policies) to list **managed policies** that are attached to the role

Then create a new role and use:

- [`put_role_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.put_role_policy) to attach an **inline policy**
- [`attach_role_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.attach_role_policy) to attach a **managed policy**

Trust Relationship also has to be copied.

Comment: Why does AWS make common tasks like this one so difficult to accomplish?

Comment: I think trust relationship is an extra needed step

Comment: As if it isn't already complex enough, I am tasked to migrate the roles to _another_ AWS account. Imagine the extra hurdle I have to go through.

Comment: @Christian Well, if the roles & infrastructure are initially deployed via Terraform or CloudFormation, then it is very easy to deploy elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if only that were the case. :(

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @JohnRotenstein for pointing in the right direction. I came up with a Node.js script to automate the IAM role copy procedure.

Steps it performs along with AWS SDK APIs used:

1. Fetch the source role along with its trust relationship policy: `getRole()`
2. Fetch inline policies of the source role: `listRolePolicies()`, `getRolePolicy()`
3. Fetch managed policies of the source role (both AWS- and customer-created): `listAttachedRolePolicies()`
4. Create a new role copying over all relevant properties (including trust policy): `createRole()`
5. Add all inline policies found in the source role to the new role: `putRolePolicy()`
6. Attach all managed policies from the source role: `attachRolePolicy()`

The process is quite straightforward... The only interesting detail is steps 2 and 3 require recursive fetch to accommodate the fact that policies response can be paginated.

[How to make a copy of AWS IAM role](https://www.maxivanov.io/copy-aws-iam-role/).

Comment: Hey Max, I just tried your script, and let me tell you it is pure love ❤️‍ Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 1):

If Python is an option, perhaps boto3 can be helpful (AWS's SDK for Python)

Creating a role:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_role

Creating a policy:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_policy

More:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#client
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html